# Blender NET_RENDER using command line

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, command-line

I want to net render my project without GUI.
I know
[blender command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html).
I also know **blender -E help**
and tried the command 
**blender -b file.blend -E NET_RENDER -s 10 -e 50 -t 2 –a**
but before running this command we need to set parameters like a master server, port etc. by GUI
Can you guide me on how to set Address(master) while net rendering through command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
blender -b -y -P master.py -noaudio --addons netrender file.blend
```

Contents of `master.py`:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module="netrender")
bpy.context.scene.render.engine="NET_RENDER"
bpy.context.scene.network_render.mode = 'RENDER_MASTER'
bpy.context.scene.network_render.path = "/tmp/"
bpy.context.scene.network_render.server_address = "[default]"
bpy.context.scene.network_render.server_port = 8200
bpy.ops.render.netclientstart()
```

For the slave you can use the same blender command with a second python script. Create a copy of `master.py`, name it `slave.py` or something and change the according line for the mode to:

```
[...]

bpy.context.scene.network_render.mode = 'RENDER_SLAVE'

[...]
```

Tested in blender 2.79a.

**Note:** this is currently broken in the latest daily builds of blender 2.80 (refer [here](https://developer.blender.org/T53666)) I'm currently searching for a workarround, to get the new gpu / host memory feature working with automated network rendering, but they'll probably fix it anyways when blender 2.80 comes out.

Comment: If you're interested in the blender 2.80 thing: Just found this seems to be working (no promises) https://www.wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Net_render